# confused with the FFT output

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I am taking  some sensor output and doing fft on it. how to get the exact frequencies from the complex output? my understanding is that bin frequencies  and the input frequencies are different. Please help. I am just a beginner in fft

Comment: Can you see peaks in the FFT output? Those should indicate the frequencies present in the signal. Also, take a  look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/9416/11619), other *Related* questions (see the right margin for a list), and also search at [DSP.StackExchange](http://dsp.stackexchange.com).

Comment: FFT output in the sense-complex values. So i want to get those frequencies which are present in the input using my complex output. I don't know whether i'm even thinking in the right way.

Comment: Compute the magnitude of these complex-valued coefficients to obtain the power spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

Let the input signal be given by $x[n]$, for $n=0,1,\dots,N-1$. We want to look at its $N$-point DFT (the FFT is just an efficient way to calculate the DFT). The $k^{\mathrm{th}}$ sample of the DFT is given by

$$
w[k] = \sum_n e^{-j2\pi k \cdot n / N} x[n]
$$

What you want to know is the frequency of this DFT bin. The frequency of the DFT bin is just the frequency of the $e^{-j2\pi k \cdot n/N}$ term, which is $2\pi \cdot k/N$. However, the units are radians per sample and you probably want something like radians per second. To convert to radians per second, all you have to do is scale the DFT's frequency by the number of samples per second, which is just the sampling frequency of the input data, $f_s$:

$$
2\pi {{k}\over{N}} \left( {{\mathrm{rad}\over{\mathrm{sample}}}} \right) \cdot f_s \left( {{\mathrm{sample}\over{\mathrm{second}}}} \right) = 2\pi f_s {{k}\over{N}} \left( {{\mathrm{rad}\over{\mathrm{second}}}} \right).
$$

Comment: Could you please make it bit more clear. As i told i am just a beginner and  I kind of feel i will fully understand if you will do that. Thanks.

Comment: I rewrote it. Hopefully it's now helpful. It occurred to me that you probably don't care about the swapping, so I left that out. However, you should read up on what the DFT spectrum represents and how the frequency range from $[0,2\pi)$ is the same as $[-\pi,\pi)$ but in a different order. This [page](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2014/09/23/sinusoids-and-fft-frequency-bins/) looks very helpful.

Comment: i understand that the concept of DFT is like-we have a signal and any signal can be represented as a sum of many sinusoids of different frequencies. When we do DFT on the signal we get the information of what all frequencies are present in the signal. So my doubt here is that -how to get those frequencies? bin frequencies are different from those present in the input signal,no? i want a clarity on this. I am confused on this aspect.

Comment: -or is it like the FFT output should be analysed with the amplitudes in each FFT **bin** and not with the amplitude at a particular frequency?

Comment: Are you asking about how to estimate which frequencies are present in a signal? I was working under the impression that you were asking about how to figure out which frequency each bin represented.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 yes exactly..about the frequencies in a signal

Comment: @vid Start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density_estimation#Frequency_estimation) and read up on the various methods. When you have specific questions, feel free to post again. You might also have luck at the [DSP site](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/).